# Laravel Many to Many Relationship Pagination with 20,000 rows

Tags: php, pagination, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a table for articles and categories, along with a pivot table; I got all related articles within a category. Using

```
$category = Category::first();
return $category->articles()->paginate(10); // many to many relationship $this->belongsToMany(Article::class, 'article_category');
```

It returns the right articles, but it is so slow when there are more than 20000 articles in a category. Is there any way to make the query faster?

note: All tables have indexes.

Comment: Did u found a answer yet? Would love to know how to fix this

Comment: Unfortunately no. I tried creating my own custom pagination, still no luck. :( I do hope a hero comes to save me.

Comment: The way i worked it out is get the ID of the user, then run a query to get all his posts for example

Answer (score 1):

I have face this quite few times.

So far the only solution that I know is TO NOT USE ELOQUENT in COMPLEX QUERY.

You have to change to DB Query Builder.

I assume you are using "whereHas" in your query. Using it will slow down a lot on your queries. If you do use it, change to DB Query with Join methods. It would be a lot faster.

The only problem is that there is no relationship you can use which you have already declared in the model. You have to manually link it back.

But recently I heard they add this relationship feature already in 5.3. But I have not yet check it out.

Hopefully this will solve the problem.